# how do I verify that this converges uniformly to $f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I had to find the fourier series for $f(x)=|x|, -\pi \le x \le \pi$
I got the fourier series as
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}cos((2n+1)x)$$
but now I have to verify that this converges uniformly to $f(x)$ and I have to evaluate the series when $x=0$. I do not know how to show convergence but for evaluating the series at $x=0$ all I have to do is find the first few terms of the sum and substitute $0$ for $x$?

Comment: As a side note, for evaluating, it doesn't make sense to claim a solution at $x=0$ if the series doesn't converge. So it is important to do that first. However, as your series does converge, to evaluate the series just substitute $x=0$ into both sides and rearrange to see what the series sums to.

Comment: @Mattos we found that the series converges, but if I substitute $0$ for $x$, how do I figure out what the sum is since the series goes to $\infty$?

Comment: The series converges uniformly, so it can't possibly go to $\infty$. Just substitute $x = 0$ into the left and right hand sides , you should get

$$0 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\pi (2n+1)^{2}}$$

then rearrange to solve for the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [p. 4 here useful](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_8.pdf).

---

Anyway,

$$|\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}cos((2n+1)x)|$$

$$\le \frac{\pi}{2}+|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}cos((2n+1)x)|$$

$$\le \frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}cos((2n+1)x)|$$

$$\le \frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}|cos((2n+1)x)|$$

$$\le \frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}$$

$$\le \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Now

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} < \infty$$

Hence

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} < \infty$$

$\therefore$, by the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#Statement),

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)^2}cos((2n+1)x)$$

converges uniformly QED

Comment: why did the $|cos((2n+1)x)|$ disappear after the fourth line?

Comment: @idknuttin  $|\cos(x)| \le 1$, $|\sin(x)| \le 1$, $|\arctan(x)| \le \pi/2$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Notice that the terms of the series drop off like $n^{-2}$. Can you use this fact to get a uniform (small) bound on $\sup_x|f(x)-S_N(x)|$, where $S_N(x)$ is the $N-$th partial sum?